# How can I determine what arguments have already been passed to a lodash partial function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let say I'm passing different data into a function in different places to work around some legacy decisions/code.

```
var partialFunction;
if(thisSituationIsCrazy(data, value)) {
    partialFunction = _.partial(originalFunciton, data)
} else {
    partialFunction = _.partialRight(originalFunction, value)
}
```

Is there a way to determine what values were actually passed in and at which place in the function? This is only for debugging purposes.

I'm hoping for something like `partialFunction.arguments` or some such that would shed some light on where it's gotten to, because the actual situation is more complicated than my example.

I've not seen a way to do it based on the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/#partial), nor on the [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L10716). I've also not seen this mentioned in any blogs on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a concept of `Higher order functions` (HOF) in functional programming, which proves very powerful for this case.

HOF is a function that wraps another function, while it adds "extra hands" to the passed function.

```js
//now a demo of what you want
function greet(a, b, c) {
  return a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c;
}

function trackArguments(fn, ctx) {
  const trackedArgs = [];
  function tracker(partialFn, ...args) {
     trackedArgs.push(...args);
     const res = fn.call(ctx, partialFn, ...args);
     res.trackedArgs = trackedArgs;
     return res;
  }
  tracker.trackedArgs = trackedArgs;
  return tracker
}
 
const trackedPartial = trackArguments(_.partial, _);

var sayHelloTo = trackedPartial(greet, 'hello', 'Stack');

console.log('Arguments passed already:', sayHelloTo.trackedArgs);

console.log('Execution works perfctly:', sayHelloTo('Overflow'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: basically its a same thing, but for this the OP need to change the source code from `_.partial(fnName, someArgs)`  to `trackedPartial(fnName, someArgs)` in all the placesn the existing project, insn't it?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee same result, true. But this is much preferred because it brings some benefits of using the functional programming paradigm, better testability, not overriding things, keeping things pure, and more readable, since you know that the _.partial will always be the same, not changing per application for example.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously that is implemented inside the function, and when you invoke the final callback, its access the actual function from closer, and that is not exposed.

However if you want that really, you can go ahead and wrap that for your purpose:

```js
//your wrapping inside a IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)
(function() {
    var _partial = _.partial,
        _partialRight = _.partialRight;
    _.partial = function() {
        var args = Array.from(arguments).slice(1),
            ret = _partial.apply(_, arguments);
        ret.args = args;
        return ret;
    }

    _.partialRight = function() {
        var args = Array.from(arguments).slice(1),
            ret = _partialRight.apply(_, arguments);
        ret.args = args;
        return ret;
    }
})();

//now a demo of what you want
function greet(a, b, c) {
  return a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c;
}
 
var sayHelloTo = _.partial(greet, 'hello', 'Stack');
console.log('Arguments passed already:', sayHelloTo.args);
console.log('Execution works perfctly:', sayHelloTo('Overflow'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's really shiny. It's also quite a lot more than I was hoping for but I could do that in a pinch. Thanks!

Comment: for you debugging purpose you can execute it even from console

Comment: I'm actually running this from a bunch karma/jasmine tests, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Then you can do it before test start, Good luck :)

Comment: the answer is good, but you can just wrap the functions with a HOF that tracks the input, then just passes them down to the function. you can call the HOF trackArguments. much simpler and less hackey.